# AS3 script not being called on gotoAndStop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am designing an app in Animate CC, and have a setup like this:

[image]

Each page is a separate 20 frame section of the timeline. The **NavigationScript** layer contains a script that handles the main navigation, and the **ImageControlScript** layer contains code to set up event listeners that are specific to each page:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
image1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openImage(144));
image2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openImage(145));
trace ("Events added");`
```

When the app starts, everything goes fine: the event listeners are added, and the `trace()` is called. However, when I navigate to another page, the script on the **ImageControlScript** layer are not called, not even the `trace` function.

If I navigate back to the first page (Frame 1), it's also not called.

The navigation script uses a `gotoAndStop` function to move between pages.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not all that familiar with AS3...

Comment: When you navigate back to Frame 1 is the trace being output?

Comment: In your gotoAndStop are you using the frame number ie: gotoAndStop(1) or gotoAndStop("About")?

Comment: The number, based on a array: var destinationFrame = pagesFrame[pageIndex];
  gotoAndStop(destinationFrame);

Comment: The code you posted seems to be taking you to 145 frame, in image there is no code on frame 145?

Comment: There is no code specifically on frame 145, but the code on frame 141 applies to frames 141 through 152. This all executes properly, it is when returning to frame 1, 21, 41, etc that the problem occurs.

Comment: And you can see assets of frame 1 but not the trace??i doubt you are returning to exact frame number you have code on.

Comment: So is code only executed if it's on a keyframe?

Comment: absolutely, playhead must jump to the keyframe have code otherwise it will bypass it.